# Update changes of own apt repository with large files fast

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, debian

Dear askUbuntu community,

In our lab, we are working with a lot of external software and configurations on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. In order to provide the corresponding packages to every coworker (nowadays we have up to 40 custom pkgs), we set up an own local APT mirror and linked it to our PXE boot. This works pretty fine since we even created an own git repository to manage our APT mirror (we change packages and their dependencies weekly and having an own apt mirror saves a lot of time for everyone). Unfortunately, our package management (providing the apt mirror) includes a lot of own scripts: if someone changes a package, a script takes this changed package, replaces it in our server, moves it to our apt mirror and an additional script uses

> sudo dpkg-scanpackages amd64 | gzip > amd64/Packages.gz

to update the Packages.gz file which basically tells the mirror what the packages contain and how they depend on each other.
As already mentioned, this works fine but applying *dpkg-scanpackages* on our packages (a lot of them contain a couple of gigabytes) **takes hours**! So, if someone changes even a small dependency in one package, we have to apply this command (which overwrites the *Package.gz* file building it from scratch on our apt mirror) which is for me completely unnecessary. Stepping over this issue, I tried to find out a more sophisticated solution to solve this problem, but I couldn't find an update feature of the Debian packaging system (or *dpkg-scanpackages*) in order to save time. And everyone knows, time is precious in development :)

Maybe I'm thinking in a wrong direction, but I I'm feeling in my guts that there is **a way better solution** for updating the *Package.gz* on our apt mirror if we just want changed e.g 3 pkgs) [Some information: A lot of our own packages require external dependencies and some of them depend on each other which makes a handish manipulation of the file not easy]
Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

Additional idea: The reason why it takes so much time for *dpkg-scanpackages* is the creation of the unique hash sum for every package. Is there (maybe) an option for the apt mirror to “workaround” this hash sum creation?

Kindest regards!